# Add caption to image in <figure> with flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, figure

I'm trying to create a gallery with figure elements having two classes: `.portrait` and `.landscape`. `.portrait`should take 25% of the width in the container and `.landscape` should take 50% of the width. I then want to put an image in each figure that should cover the element using `object-fit: cover`. The container is a flex-box container.

Everything works perfect when just working with images. I get them to have their assigned width and then have a consistent height automatically so that each row looks the same height-wise. However, I would like to add captions to each figure, but when doing so, the caption gets overlapped by the images.

Is there any way to have the captions without the overlap, keeping the same behaviour with the automatic height? I've tried to set the container to `align-items: flex-start` which then leaves the caption's not overlapping, but instead, the height gets inconsistent with the `.portrait` class having more height than `.landscape`.

Here's the HTML and CSS of what I have so far:

```css
#container {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

figure {
  margin:0;  
}

figure.portrait {
  width:25%;
}

figure.landscape {
  width:50%;
}

figure img {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <figure class="landscape">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="portrait">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a7/38/ce/a738ceec705d4cb698eb9840818fe4d4--mini-husky-alaskan-klee-kai.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="portrait">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a7/38/ce/a738ceec705d4cb698eb9840818fe4d4--mini-husky-alaskan-klee-kai.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="portrait">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a7/38/ce/a738ceec705d4cb698eb9840818fe4d4--mini-husky-alaskan-klee-kai.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="landscape">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SfLV8hD7zX4/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
    <figcaption>Hello</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEPxqB

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, I'll fix that.

Comment: So where is the caption supposed to be ...an overlay or under the image? Plus if you use `object-fit` there's nowhere for the caption to fit... *that's kinda the point*.

Comment: It's supposed to be under the image. It's very true that the `object-fit` fills out the whole space. But is there a way to get the image to fill 50% or 25% of the width, then have the height as close to the original aspect ratio as possible and then leave space for the caption underneath?

Comment: You could wrap each image in it's own container with width:100%....that might work.

Comment: ...but there is no mechanism to equalise heights of the images then.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/xPbLmM

Comment: Hmm. That actually could work with some tweaking. Thank you very much!